# Save files to sql server using windows app without Filestream

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, windows

I want to upload a file to a sql server, but when looking at code, all the solutions I seem to either use Filestream or SQLConnect, neither of which are of any use to me. I write in c# with windows applications. 
I use the datacontext-class and a Datamodel namespace to call to the database.
Any help at all is apprectiated

Comment: Do you want to store the binary stream of the file in the database? Or just a filepath to the file on disk?

Comment: What do you mean by, "upload file to sql server"? Do you want to store the file in a record in the database or as a file on the HD, outside the database. Is this a WPF application?

Comment: I want to store the entire file in the database, not just the path :) It's a windows store grid app, but this part of the app is just a blank windows app page.
@NathanSkerl

Comment: How will the data be used most of the time? Though SQL Server has types that support up to 2GB, Filestream is highly efficient and puts a minimal load on SQL Server especially when the files are more than a few KB in size. There are quite a few examples in codeplex, msdn and other places. Here's one that might help: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Insert-Word-Document-Files-into-SQL-Server-Database-Table-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: It will be as a mini-dropbox, but it'll only be used to save documents. I found those examples, but I don't have the support of neither asp or sqlCommand available. @SQLmojoe

Comment: The C# sample is generic; it's not limited to asp.net. SQLCommand is a standard C# class in the SQLClient namespace. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx. It takes a bit more effort to learn but IMHO, it's well worth it. I'm not fond on what LINQ generates but if you must use DataContext, it still has executecommand and executequery methods where you can run TSQL for the insert (e.g. INSERT INTO myminidropbox(filebox) 
SELECT * FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\File01.docx', SINGLE_BLOB) -- filebox is a varbinary column for storing the file)

Comment: So if you gave your opinion, I should switch from LINQ to SQLCommand? I might very well do this, as I'm pretty new to LINQ too. 
Thank you @SQLmojoe, wish I could give you a thumb up or something :)